# How to reverse a contingency table to get the data in R

Tags: r

If I have a contingency table provided, how to reverse engineer to get the data.

Example:

```
library(MASS)
table(Cars93$Type, Cars93$Origin) # this gives the contingency table
```

Now I just want the dataframe with two columns Cars93$Type and Cars93$Origin from the contingency table.

I tried searching online but couldn't find anything relevant.

Can anybody help here?

Comment: `tab <- table(Cars93$Type, Cars93$Origin); 
DF <- as.data.frame(tab); 
data.frame(Type = rep(DF$Var1, DF$Freq), Origin = rep(DF$Var2, DF$Freq))`

Comment: What if the contingency table is given to me in a dataframe format like data.frame(A = c(6,4,1),B= c(4,12,12),C = c(1,3,2),row.names = c('A2','B2','C2'))

Comment: I tried to use melt, but I only get two columns, one with column names and other one has frequency.

Comment: You can use `melt`. You just have to first do `DF$rn <- rownames(DF)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::uncount`:

```r
tab <- table(Cars93$Type, Cars93$Origin)

setNames(tidyr::uncount(as.data.frame(tab), Freq), c("Type", "Origin"))
#>          Type  Origin
#> 1     Compact     USA
#> 1.1   Compact     USA
#> 1.2   Compact     USA
#> 1.3   Compact     USA
#> 1.4   Compact     USA
#> 1.5   Compact     USA
#> 1.6   Compact     USA
#> 2       Large     USA
#> 2.1     Large     USA
#> 2.2     Large     USA
#> 2.3     Large     USA
#> 2.4     Large     USA
#> 2.5     Large     USA
#> 2.6     Large     USA
#> 2.7     Large     USA
#> 2.8     Large     USA
#> 2.9     Large     USA
#> 2.10    Large     USA
#> 3     Midsize     USA
#> 3.1   Midsize     USA
#> 3.2   Midsize     USA
#> 3.3   Midsize     USA
#> 3.4   Midsize     USA
#> 3.5   Midsize     USA
#> 3.6   Midsize     USA
#> 3.7   Midsize     USA
#> 3.8   Midsize     USA
#> 3.9   Midsize     USA
#> 4       Small     USA
#> 4.1     Small     USA
#> 4.2     Small     USA
#> 4.3     Small     USA
#> 4.4     Small     USA
#> 4.5     Small     USA
#> 4.6     Small     USA
#> 5      Sporty     USA
#> 5.1    Sporty     USA
#> 5.2    Sporty     USA
#> 5.3    Sporty     USA
#> 5.4    Sporty     USA
#> 5.5    Sporty     USA
#> 5.6    Sporty     USA
#> 5.7    Sporty     USA
#> 6         Van     USA
#> 6.1       Van     USA
#> 6.2       Van     USA
#> 6.3       Van     USA
#> 6.4       Van     USA
#> 7     Compact non-USA
#> 7.1   Compact non-USA
#> 7.2   Compact non-USA
#> 7.3   Compact non-USA
#> 7.4   Compact non-USA
#> 7.5   Compact non-USA
#> 7.6   Compact non-USA
#> 7.7   Compact non-USA
#> 7.8   Compact non-USA
#> 9     Midsize non-USA
#> 9.1   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.2   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.3   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.4   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.5   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.6   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.7   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.8   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.9   Midsize non-USA
#> 9.10  Midsize non-USA
#> 9.11  Midsize non-USA
#> 10      Small non-USA
#> 10.1    Small non-USA
#> 10.2    Small non-USA
#> 10.3    Small non-USA
#> 10.4    Small non-USA
#> 10.5    Small non-USA
#> 10.6    Small non-USA
#> 10.7    Small non-USA
#> 10.8    Small non-USA
#> 10.9    Small non-USA
#> 10.10   Small non-USA
#> 10.11   Small non-USA
#> 10.12   Small non-USA
#> 10.13   Small non-USA
#> 11     Sporty non-USA
#> 11.1   Sporty non-USA
#> 11.2   Sporty non-USA
#> 11.3   Sporty non-USA
#> 11.4   Sporty non-USA
#> 11.5   Sporty non-USA
#> 12        Van non-USA
#> 12.1      Van non-USA
#> 12.2      Van non-USA
#> 12.3      Van non-USA
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it was that simple. Do you know if there's another way without using tidyr?

Comment: @animus yes, you can use `rep` to build the data frame as @Roland showed in his comment if you would prefer to avoid dependencies.